# C# parsing Request

Tags: c#, parsing, webserver, httprequest

I'm working on a webserver for university. I have a problem at parsing the request, i get from the client-browser. When I'm asking the streamreader for endofstream, it always cancel process without any error-message. Just the console pop-up and nothing else happen anymore. Debug-Mode is the same problem, if im asking in debug-mode if the streamreader is always endofstream i get errormessage that this function is cancelled, because of timeout.

```
private void ParseRequest()
    {
        string _readContent = string.Empty;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(network);

        //Überprüfe ob der stream null ist, wenn nicht dann führe parsen aus, falls null return false
        if (sr != null)
        {
            //lese die erste Zeile ein, in dieser muss methode und url enthalten sein
            string Method_URL_Line = sr.ReadLine();

            string _headerLine;

            //splitte die eingelesene Zeile bei jeden leerzeichen
            if (Method_URL_Line != null)
            {
                method = Method_URL_Line.Split(' ');
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }
            //überprüfe ob die erste Zeile korrekt geschickt wurde und parse die methode und url in eigene string variablen
            if (method.Length == 3)
            {
                parsed_method = method[0];
                parsed_url = method[1];
                parsed_method = parsed_method.ToUpper();
            }

            //lese solange aus dem Stream, bis er am Ende angelangt ist
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                _headerLine = sr.ReadLine();

                if (_headerLine == string.Empty)
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        contentString += sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    _headerPairs = _headerLine.Split(':');

                    if (_headerPairs.Length >= 2)
                    {
                        if (_headerPairs.Length == 3)
                        {
                            _headers.Add(_headerPairs[0].ToLower(), _headerPairs[1].Trim() + ":" + _headerPairs[2].Trim());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //füge die Key,Value Pairs den Dictionary hinzu und lösche beim Value die Whitespaces am Anfang und Ende.
                            _headers.Add(_headerPairs[0].ToLower(), _headerPairs[1].Trim());                                
                        }
                        _headerCount++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (contentString == string.Empty) contentString = null;                
        }
    }
```

Finally all works well, until i reach the newline, which should be the marker that content starts after it. But i guess, if there is no content, there is still a problem i didnt find yet. Any Ideas how i can solve that problem?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What exactly does the network variable hold? Do you have an url I can test ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's done :) Finally I worked with binaryreader and -writer. The problem was that there was no EndofStream because the connection was not closed. But the HTTP header gives information about the length of the content, so I'm reading just as much content as specified in content-length